# Notation for partial derivative of matrix function times vector function

Tags: matrix-calculus

**Question:** 
What is a compact notation for expressing the quantity?

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} D^2 \mathbf{F}( \mathbf{g}(x) ) \mathbf{h}(x)
\tag{Q} 
$$

---

To be concrete and keep things simple (clearly this can be generalized to other dimensions), let's suppose: $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, $\mathbf{F}( \mathbf{z} ) = \mathbf{F}(z_1, z_2)$, $\mathbf{g}(x) = ( g_1(x), g_2(x) )$, and $\mathbf{h}(x) = (h_1(x), h_2(x))$. Thus, we have the Hessian as,

$$ 
D^2 \mathbf{F}(z) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial^2 F / \partial z_1 \partial z_1 &  \partial^2 F / \partial z_1 \partial z_2 \\ 
\partial^2 F / \partial z_1 \partial z_2 &  \partial^2 F / \partial z_2 \partial z_2   
\end{bmatrix} 
=: 
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{11} & F_{12} \\  
F_{12} & F_{22} 
\end{bmatrix} 
$$ 
Hence, we know that $D^2 \mathbf{F}( \mathbf{g}(x) ) \mathbf{h}(x)$ is a $(2 \times 2)(2 \times 1) = 2 \times 1$ vector, and thus $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} D^2 \mathbf{F}( \mathbf{g}(x) ) \mathbf{h}(x)$ is also a $2 \times 1$ vector.

The difficultly that I'm having is the following. If I brute force expand out $D^2 \mathbf{F}( \mathbf{g}(x) ) \mathbf{h}(x)$ and just take derivative $\partial / \partial x_i$ element-by-element and apply the product rule, I end up with a quantity that looks like:

$$
\begin{align} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} D^2 \mathbf{F}( \mathbf{g}(x) ) \mathbf{h}(x)
&= D^2 \mathbf{F}( \mathbf{g}(x) ) \frac{\partial \mathbf{h}(x)}{\partial x_i} + 
\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} D^2 \mathbf{F}( \mathbf{g}(x) ) \right) \mathbf{h}(x)   
\end{align} 
$$

My trouble is with writing a compact notation for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} D^2 \mathbf{F}( \mathbf{g}(x) )$. Writing the terms out, I see that, 
$$
\begin{align} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} D^2 \mathbf{F}( \mathbf{g}(x) )
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial F_{11}(\mathbf{g}) / \partial x_i & \partial F_{12}(\mathbf{g}) / \partial x_i \\ 
\partial F_{12}(\mathbf{g}) / \partial x_i & \partial F_{22}(\mathbf{g}) / \partial x_i 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align} 
$$
Applying the chain rule say for the first element (similar for the other 3 elements), I see that,

$$
\begin{align}  
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} F_{11}(\mathbf{g}) 
&= \frac{\partial F_{11}}{\partial z_1} \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_i} + \frac{\partial F_{11}}{\partial z_2} \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_i} \\
&=: ( \nabla_z F_{11} )^\top ( \nabla_{x_i} \mathbf{g} ) 
\end{align} 
$$
which means the above has the form,

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} D^2 \mathbf{F}( \mathbf{g}(x) )
=
\begin{bmatrix}
( \nabla_z F_{11} )^\top ( \nabla_{x_i} \mathbf{g} )  & ( \nabla_z F_{12} )^\top ( \nabla_{x_i} \mathbf{g} ) \\ 
( \nabla_z F_{12} )^\top ( \nabla_{x_i} \mathbf{g} )  & ( \nabla_z F_{22} )^\top ( \nabla_{x_i} \mathbf{g} ) 
\end{bmatrix} 
\tag{1} 
$$

---

*** In all: *** Is there a compact notation for expressing the right hand side of (1), which then solves my question to (Q)?